# SQL query to find duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

I am trying to write a query in SQL server to find out if there are any multiple rows for each hash value.
 
I need all filenames where the hash value has duplicates.

The result should be (based on my example below)

```
003B4C68BC143B0290E04432A3A96092    File0003.jpg
003B4C68BC143B0290E04432A3A96092    File0004.jpg
003B4C68BC143B0290E04432A3A96092    File0005.jpg
```

Please let me know.

Here is the table structure

```
File table
-----------------------------------------
hash          FileName
---------------------------------------
000341A486F5492877D588BED0806650    File0001.jpg
00363EF2ECEEA32F10176EB64A50283F    File0002.jpg
003B4C68BC143B0290E04432A3A96092    File0003.jpg
003B4C68BC143B0290E04432A3A96092    File0004.jpg
003B4C68BC143B0290E04432A3A96092    File0005.jpg
```

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select * 
from File 
where hash in (select 
               hash 
               from File
               group by hash
               having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `EXISTS` to check for duplicates,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Tablename b
            WHERE   a.hash = b.hash
            GROUP   BY hash
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d124/1)

or `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    [File] a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  hash
            FROM    [File] b
            GROUP   BY hash
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON  a.hash = b.hash
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d124/3)